# Adding members to twitter list not working?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm absolutely stumped why this isn't working, so reaching out to the crowd here.

I'm trying to do something pretty basic - add a user to a list I created. And NOTHING is working.

```
@consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(twitter_client.consumer_key,twitter_client.consumer_secret, :site => "https://api.twitter.com/")
@client = OAuth::AccessToken.from_hash(@consumer, {:oauth_token => twitter_client.access_token, :oauth_token_secret => twitter_client.access_token_secret})
me = JSON.parse @client.get("/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json").body
screen_name = me["screen_name"]
handles.each do |sub_handles|
  res = @client.post("/1.1/lists/members/create.json", {:user_id => me["user_id"], :owner_screen_name => screen_name, :slug => l.slug,  :screen_name => sub_handles}, {'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' })
  puts res.to_hash.inspect
  puts res.body
end
```

And getting back:

```
{"errors":[{"code":104,"message":"You aren't allowed to add members to this list."}]}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The API request obviously works, because the JSON response is an error from Twitter, not from the network. You probably need to extend the permission set of the token you are using with the API thru Twitter settings.

Answer (score 1):

There is an old answer that the (unpublished) write limits kick in quite soon for small apps.  So this is likely if you are trying to add a large number of users and it is happening after a small number were successful.

https://twittercommunity.com/t/cant-add-members-to-a-list-code-104/25824/3

> Read operation API limits are reported in rate_limit_status (and in
>   the rate limit header on the response from an API call); but the
>   posting / update limits are not. This is because these values are
>   adaptive and may vary at times of high traffic, or if the system
>   suspects that something suspicious is going on.